# Django Rest Framework Request Validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to validate params that are passed with the request without writing boilerplate code? Now I've got something like this:

```
    project_id = kwargs['project_id']

    try:
        project_obj = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    except Project.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(
            {'message': 'Requested project does not exist'},
            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )
    except ValueError:
        return Response(
            {'message': 'Project id must be a number'},
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
```

I've read about Serializers' Validation but I'm not sure it's the right thing. Without handling these exceptions, Django just returns 500, it's not the behavior I actually want.

Comment: I don't know of a clever way to check to see if an objects exists in the database with, you know, checking to see if it's in the database.  I suppose a cheesy way would be to get a list of the all the `project_id`s and see if your ID passed in is in that list.  To the other error you are catching, `ValueError`, you can write a simple check to see if `project_id` is a number and if not simply send back an error of your choice instead of catching the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to wind up writing some boilerplate, but you can clean what you have up by specifying relevant field types like using an [`IntegerField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#integerfield) would spare you checking the type and [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) would spare you the try/ catch in those cases.

However, you really want to use the real *right* field for this job and it's going to be a [Relation field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/), most likely `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.